# Not getting Proper response from Jmeter when using SOAP Web service

Tags: web-services, soap, jmeter

I am trying to do some SOAP web service testing from Jmeter for POST methods. But I am not getting proper response. Please find some of the conditions and their exceptions below.

```
    1) Implementation = HttpClinet4     
    Request: POST http://example.com/getInfo
    With Post body request
    Response: <HEAD><TITLE>Authentication Required</TITLE></HEAD>
    <!-- default "Authentication Required" response (307) -->
    </BODY>
```

Status : Pass

```
    2) Implementation = HttpClinet3 

    Request: POST http://example.com/getInfo

    With Post body request

    Response: <HEAD><TITLE>internal error - server connection terminated</TITLE></HEAD>
        Description: internal error - server connection terminated</B></FONT>
    <HR>
    <!-- default "internal error - server connection terminated" response (502) -->
    </BODY>
```

Status : Fail

```
    3) Implementation = Java

    Request: POST http://example.com/getInfo/With some garbage value

    With Post body request

    Response: 
    Description: internal error - server connection terminated</B></FONT>
    <HR>
    <!-- default "internal error - server connection terminated" response (502) -->
    </BODY>
```

Status : Fail

Why I am getting three different request and responses for different implementations? Which one should I use?
Note: I am running my Jmeter behind proxy with proper details from command prompt.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you show your test plan by unfolding all nodes ?
thx

Comment: @UBIKLOADPACK, The issue was related to Proxies. Hence for different implementation its different request.The issues are still exists. I am running my scripts without opening them via proxies for the time being.